# Laravel testing. Get rout autoredirects from "/signin" to "am/signin", when for post I need to manually write "am/signin". Why post acts like this?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing

1. I use `Laravel 9`, but it is updated version. I mean, the project was written in `laravel 5.4` and **updated it to 9 later**.
2. Here's my routes

   ```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'locale', 'prefix' => '{locale?}'], function () {

        Route::get('/signin', 'Front\UsersController@getSignin');
        Route::post('/signin', 'Front\UsersController@postSignin'); 

    });
   ```
3. Here's my tests

   ```
   public function test_get_signin(){
        $response = $this->get('/signin');
        $response->assertStatus(302);
   }

   public function test_post_signin(){
        $response = $this->post('am/signin');
        $response->assertStatus(302);
   }
   ```

It works well when I do `$this->post('am/signin');`

But it is not correct. By the idea it must work when I write `$this->post('/signin')` without manually adding what should be added automatically. But in fact I get **status code 405**.

4. UsersController method for post('/signin) route.

   ```
   public function postSignin($lang, Request $request){

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if (Auth::validate(['email' => $request['email'],'password' => $request['password']])
            || Auth::validate(['username' => $request['email'],'password' => $request['password']])) {
            $verify = User::where(['email'=> $request['email']])->first();
            $verify = $verify?$verify:User::where(['username'=> $request['email']])->first();

            if($verify->status =='blocked'){
                if ($request->expectsJson()) {
                    return response()->json(array('verify'=> trans('email.profile-block')), 422);
                }
            }elseif(!$verify->verified){
                return response()->json(array('verify'=> trans('validation.active_account').' '
                    .trans('car.click').' <a class="resend-link" href="/'.$lang.'/resendtoken/'.$verify->email_token
                    .'">'.trans('car.here1').'</a> '.trans('validation.resend_link')), 422);
            }elseif($verify->status =='pending'){
                return response()->json(array('verify'=> trans('car.company_napp')), 422);
            }elseif($verify->status =='active'){

                if(filter_var($request->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                    $field = 'email';
                }else{
                    $field = 'username';
                }
                if (Auth::attempt([$field => $request->email, 'password'=>$request->password],$request->remember)) {
                    UserLoginInfo::create(['user_id'=>Auth::id(),'ip_address'=> $request->ip(),
                        'info'=>json_encode(self::get_user_info())]);
                    if ($request->remember) {
                        User::where('id', Auth::id())->update(array('signed_in_for_remember_me' => Carbon::now()));
                    }

                    return Auth::user()->balance;

                }
            }
        }
        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
   ```

more short:

```
$this->get('/signin');    gives status code 302
        
$this->post('am/signin'); gives status code 302
 
$this->post('/signin'); gives status code 405
```

I tried

1. to use `withoutMiddleware()`  - no positive result.

   ```
   public function test_get_signin(){
      $response = $this->withoutMiddleware('locale')->get('/signin');
      $response->assertStatus(302);
   }

   public function test_post_signin(){
      $response = $this->withoutMiddleware('locale')->post('/signin');
      $response->assertStatus(302);
   }
   ```
2. removed `"?"` symbol from `'prefix' => '{locale?}'` in route group   - no use.
3. commented the : `Route::get('/signin', 'Front\UsersController@getSignin');` *- no use again.*
4. instead of `withoutMiddleware('locale')` I also used just a `withoutMiddleware()` - no use again.

**IMPORTANT!**

Both routes work well when testing with browser. I mean. User can enter his signin page and also successfully be signed in.

What's going on? How can I force post to work automatically with **"/signin"**? It's also weird, if I manually have to write **"am/"** then why it returns 302 instead of 200?

Update

---

I created a new project and tried to experiment there with route group and get, post methods.

Here's the routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'locale', 'prefix' => '{locale?}'], function () {
    Route::get('/test', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::post('/test', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

here's the tests

```
public function test_1()
{
    $response = $this->get('/test');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}

public function test_2()
{
    $response = $this->post('/test');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

test1 and test2, both of them return status 404

And when I use tests like this, I mean, adding a prefix manually

```
public function test_1()
{
    $response = $this->get('/am/test');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}

public function test_2()
{
    $response = $this->post('/am/test');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

both of them return 200

This is good, very good. But why in my situation of my current project I get for get method 200 instead of 404 and for post 405 instead of 404, I don't have an idea. The interesting fact.  I commented the whole exceptions Handler.php's code and no use. The get method everytime returns 200 when it must return 404.

Update 2

---

I've got some new interesting info from my experiments. If in my current project I want to test get method with uri "/signin" without '/am' part with $this->withoutMiddleware(); then I get 500, but without $this->withoutMiddleware(); I get 200

And to know what 500 want to say I used $response->dd(); and got this result

> Spatie\LaravelIgnition\Exceptions\ViewException: Undefined variable
> $errors in file
> C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\storage\framework\views\7ced869fcb986989ef0f5838d6567d1b5fa4f895.php
> on line 1

And if use $this->withoutExceptionHandling(); instead of $response->dd();
We'll get this result

```
Illuminate\View\ViewException : Undefined variable $errors (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\resources\views\front\transport\index.blade.php)
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\storage\framework\views\7ced869fcb986989ef0f5838d6567d1b5fa4f895.php:1
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine.php:60
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine.php:61
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php:139
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php:122
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php:91
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php:69
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php:35
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:833
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:802
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:725
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:141
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:116
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:726
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:703
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:667
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:656
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:167
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:141
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:116
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:142
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:111
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:526
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:293
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\tests\Feature\RoutesTesting.php:1718
 
 Caused by
 ErrorException: Undefined variable $errors
 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php:255
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\storage\framework\views\7ced869fcb986989ef0f5838d6567d1b5fa4f895.php:1
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:107
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:108
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine.php:58
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine.php:61
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php:139
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php:122
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php:91
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php:69
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php:35
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:833
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:802
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:725
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:141
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:116
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:726
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:703
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:667
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:656
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:167
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:141
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:116
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:142
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:111
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:526
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:293
 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\test\hayvcar\tests\Feature\RoutesTesting.php:1718
```

Comment: Please share codes in `postSignin` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried delete cached files?

Delete everything in `bootstrap\cache` and try again on host.

I've explained the whole situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72544482/laravel9-deployment-on-shared-hosting-new-added-api-routes-not-found-postman-4/72545434?noredirect=1#comment128157830_72545434), for another question, which in this case, it doesn't matter if it's testing or using in browser, when you cache your routes, `laravel` look for the cached file, instead of defined routes in `web.php and api.php`.

So if in cached file, you've had route with `am/signin` then, doesn't matter if you change it to `signin` or not, in `web.php/api.php`, it always looking for cached file, which in this case is `am/signin`.

Temporary questions, answer them by question number :

1. So you've commented everything in `postSignin` method, and didn't worked or just a part of it?
2. You said in browser is working, method is getting `$lang` from route? because in tests, as far as i can see, you're not passing anything.
3. Have you tried to change `post` to `patch` just for test? (that's because of `Patch` verb)
4. You might also try `withoutExceptionHandling();` to get more details on error and test output. are you posting full test or just a basic test?

   - You can add this line to top of your test, `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` and get more details.
5. Remove `$lang` from method or just try a new method like below:

```
public function postSignin(Request $request){
 return something or return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request); or etc.
}
```

6. How did you upgraded your project to Laravel 9? Create a new Laravel project and only test these two routes, `get` and `post`.

Comment: Yes. I tried. No result.

Comment: Tried just now. And after that recreated bootstrap\cache file. No result. I mean. The status code 405 left without changes.

Comment: I updated the question and added the signin method code for post request.  I already commented and uncommented the code in that method. No any changes.

Comment: 1) everything commented/uncommented-no use  2) in tests if I pass anything it works nearly fine, I mean, instead of ''/signin" write "/am/signin" 3) if I use "/am/signin" and get-then status code is 200, if post-then status code is 200, if patch - then 405, but if uri will be "/signin" then if get-status is 302, but the post and patch, both throw 405, 4) if I use "/signin" and get-then no Exception, if post-then "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.", if patch-then "The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Comment: If I use "/am/signin" and get - then no Exception, if post - then "CSRF token mismatch", if patch - then "The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST."

Comment: In exception handler I commented the return statements... now the post returns 419 instead of 200. In short. Post with "/signin" brings 405 and with "/am/signin" brings 419.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan Updated, check 5 and 6.

Comment: 5) no use   6) created new project and tested it (a bit later I'll write the details).  Some useful information:       If in current project postSignin method of controller has no return and no code and $lang is commented too and in this situation use test with "$this->withoutMiddleware();" and "$response = $this->post('/am/signin');"  then status 200 is being returned, but if "/signin" without "/am" then 405.  If same  do but with test for get method instead of post then if "/am/signin" then status is 200 but if "/signin" without "/am" then the same "200".

Comment: But, if in getsignin method of controller write abort(500); then again do test for get method, for '/signin' we'll have 200, but for '/am/signin'  we'll have 500. The part with new project I'll write in my question update. Wait a few minutes.